# Rails - json.erb template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, api

I have been trying to figure out a way to customize JSON with special fields, custom formats, etc etc.  I have created an as_json and to_xml method in my model to formulate the object how I need.  This works well but it is sloppy because some of my helper methods had to move into the model, because I need the formats in the helpers and model.  I also think it is sloppy code and makes the model out of control.

I have been able to get a format with json.erb working but don't think it is working 100% correct either and the callback doesn't append either.  Anyone get this working

Here is what I got so far.

api calls format.json

template called is items.json.erb

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
<%= { :item => { :id => item.id, :name => item.name }.to_json.html_safe  %>
<% end %>
```

This works but seems odd.  Anyone have suggestions or have a way to do this?

btw  did this for the callback to work

```
<%= params[:callback]+"(" if params[:callback]  %>
<% @items.each do |item| %>
    <%= { :item => { :id => item.id, :name => item.name }.to_json.html_safe  %>
<% end %>
<%= ")" if params[:callback]  %>
```

Comment: I might be misunderstanding you, but I don't see how this could work at all. You're at least missing a closing `}` and I believe that you would need to return a array `[]` containing the objects in order to create a proper JSON structure. `[{1:'foo'},{2:'bar'},…]`.

Comment: Yes sorry I cut the whole json out because it was long....It was missing a } but it does work and I don't know why to be honest.  I did try to do <%= json=[]%> then json.push(item.json) then did the to_json.  Do you know of a way to do this correctly? (thank you for responding)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the best way to do this would be to skip the `erb` template if you don't absolutely need if for some reason. Then you could do something like this:

```
items = Item.all
render :json => items.to_json(:only => [:id, :name]), :callback => params[:callback]
```

You can override the `to_json` method in your model to add fields or call methods.

Comment: Polarblau,  I'm actually doing something similar to this in the model by overwriting the as_json method cause I need a bunch of custom fields.  For instance, I'm using a few fields were I'm storing a date but need to create a custom value for the date, like 1 year and 8 months string instead of the date.  So i'm trying to figure out how to do that with your suggestion.  Do you know how to do that instead then the template wouldn't be relavant.

Comment: How are you creating this value? Are you using a view helper?

Comment: I was thinking of moving to json.erb files as well, since there a bunch of view helpers I use to generate links that I want to send back in that json. Including the helpers in the model make it clunky, so I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: I can recommend RABL (https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) for more complex JSON structures. Overriding `as_json` in the model isn't very elegant IMO and using view helpers in a model breaks MVC.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answer to polarblau, you should override the as_json method and use the :methods parameter to include method results in your json

```
class Item

  def date
    return "1 year and 8 months" #obviously use logic here
  end

  def as_json(args={})
    super(:methods=>[:date], :only=>[:id=>:name])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you'll want to either:

1. use custom finder sql to alter column names/perform calculations (it's much faster than Ruby):

   `MyModel.select('col_name_that_needs_renamed AS new_name').order('some_col DESC')`

   or a more complicated example:

   `MyModel.find_by_sql('SELECT col_name_that_needs_renamed AS new_name, foo_col*50 AS math WHERE foo=bar ORDER some_col LIMIT 8')`
2. if there's something you can't do (or can't figure out) in SQL, you *may* have to revert to Ruby (although not recommended because it's significantly slower)

   [API Dock for to_json](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json)